# Whitespace causing problems in regex to capture addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble creating regex to capture icelandic home addresses.

Icelandic addresses can have a couple of formats

- address 3
- address 3b
- add-ress
- add-ress 2453
- ad dr ess

Basically almost any form of a sentence and then an optional number and letter.

I have come up with the following regex.

```
^(\D+)\s*?(\d+\w*)?
```

Now this works pretty well except that the \D+ is greedy and always consumes the whitespace between the number and the street/house name.

I've tried many different quantifiers and also tried positive and negative lookups without success.

I know I can always trim the whitespace from the address after this has been captured in code but i want to know if there is any way to do this properly using Regex.

Comment: Is `address3b` allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just group the separating space with the optional number group, but make sure it's excluded from the captured group.

```
^(\D+)(?:\s+(\d+\w*))?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "one or more non-digits" (`\D+`), you want "one or more non-digits, of which the last one is also non-whitespace", i.e. "zero or more non-digits, plus one non-whitespace–non-digit" (`\D*[^\d\s]`):

```
^(\D*[^\d\s])\s*?(\d+\w*)?
```

Comment: And in "\s*?" sign "?" no need, there is no point to make it lazy, basically it even should be "\s+" cos i'm assume address is never become like "add-ress2453" so it 1 or more not 0 or more